# Will postgresql generate index automatically?

Tags: postgresql

is there automatic index in Postgresql or need users to create index explicitly? if there is automatic index, how can I view it? thanks.

Comment: Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl.html

Comment: PostgreSQL will automatically create an index for the primary key of a table, when you create the table. On the command line, it will tell you that it creates it and it's name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An index on the primary key and unique constraints will be made automatically.  Use [`CREATE INDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) to make more indexes.  To view existing database structure including the indexes, use `\d table`.

A quick example of generating an index would be:

```
CREATE INDEX unique_index_name ON table (column);
```

You can create an index on multiple columns:

```
CREATE INDEX unique_index_name ON table (column1, column2, column3);
```

Or a partial index which will only exist when conditions are met:

```
CREATE INDEX unique_index_name ON table (column) WHERE column > 0;
```

There is a lot more you can do with them, but that is for the documentation (linked above) to tell you. Also, if you create an index on a production database, use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` (it will take longer, but not lock out new writes to the table). Let me know if you have any other questions.

---

**Update:**

If you want to view indexes with pure SQL, look at the `pg_catalog.pg_indexes` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes
WHERE schemaname='public'
AND tablename='table';
```

Comment: ok, when I create index on primary key manually, I found the query plan is different from no explicit index plan. why does this happen?

Comment: You would need to update your question with both query plans. There are many index types, so this may be causing differences (PostgreSQL won't use an index if it doesn't think it will be more efficient than a sequential scan).

Comment: Can I view the index by SQL query? as I'm using pgadmin debuging and can not use \d.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, I created an index (CREATE INDEX full_edge_idx ON full_edge (edge);), there is no result if I run the up query. If I run  (CREATE INDEX full_edge_idx ON full_edge (edge);) again, it shows ERROR: relation "full_edge_idx" already exists SQL state: 42P07.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes WHERE tablename='full_edge';`.

Comment: I saw my fault, thanks. another question, if I don't create index explicitly, and the query of SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_indexes WHERE tablename='full_edge'; returns nothing. does this mean, although the postgresql can create an index, it thinks it not worth to use the index so it does not create the index?

Comment: Not quite, the only time PostgreSQL will make an index is for primary keys (and some other odd ones like unique constraints). My comment about "won't use an index if it doesn't think it will be more efficient" refers to indexes that ***already*** exist.  For instance, you could create an index on a column, but if there are only a handful of rows of data the query planner may opt to *not* use the index.

Comment: Exclusion constraints also adds its index automatically (though not commonly used) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION